# How to send data into an OpenOffice word template from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, npm, openoffice-writer

How can I get data passed from NodeJS into placeholders of a OpenOffice template file? Is there any npm packages available to parse an ODT template file so that I can print data into it?

I have a 13 page word file (a template for printing reports) and I want to populate it with certain details from the DB into the different pages of this file. I like to pass the data in JSON format.

What I know is how to write into a plain text/excel file from node, but I want to write into the placeholders of a word template without loosing other parts of the template. I did the same with VBScript (with microsoft word template) in the past. Now want to achieve the same using nodejs. Please share with me your ideas..thanks

Comment: I wrote a library to do what you need. But is written in Python. You may check it at https://github.com/christopher-ramirez/secretary.

Comment: @ChristopherRamírez thanks..you have written exactly what I want. But, I need it in node. Anyway, if I didn't get other out of the box solution, at least I can go through your code to see if I can create a node-package from it.

Comment: @jasnan did you create it? I'd be interested in the result !